# How to change the value of id or name?

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
<table id ='table'>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td><select id='old' name='old'></select></td>
<td><select id='old2' name='old2'></select></td>
<td><div id='old3' name='old3'></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**How to change the value of id or name** from select id ='*old*' to select id ='*new*' (for example) after deleting rows in javascript?
I have been trying all the methods like trying getElementById('old') = 'new' but not work, used replaceChild also not work (or maybe I put the wrong code, no idea).
Do you have other alternatives? (No JQuery, please).

Thanks.

Comment: you don't mention whether the numbering of other rows should change

Comment: @ninjagecko Oh yeah the other rows should change too, same as the example I gave, if old2 change to new2, old3 to new3 so on.

Comment: @KitHo Just want to know and learn this with Javascript (it doesn't mean I don't like JQuery or don't want to use/learn), besides I have  used Javascript already, if I change to JQuery I will confuse :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the setAttribute method to accomplish this

```
document.getElementById("old").setAttribute("id","new");
document.getElementById("new").setAttribute("name","new");
```

Comment: Note that on the _second line_ I have called the element from the new Id I assigned on the _first line_

Comment: Maybe you did it that way just to demonstrate that the id has changed, but wouldn't you store the initial element reference in a variable and then set both properties from that variable rather than calling `.getElementById()` again?

Comment: Yes I did that to show that the id has changed and can be accessed by the new one you assigned without a problem. But like you said, it is preferred to store a ref and save both attributes from that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var sel = document.getElementById("old");  //Reference the element
sel.id = "new";  //set the id
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 document.getElementById("old").name = 'NewName';
 alert(document.getElementById("old").name);
 document.getElementById("old").id = 'Newid';
 alert(document.getElementById("Newid").id);
```

its work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I feel there is something inelegant going on here; if you told us more we'd be able to say the "right way" to do it. If you nevertheless have a very good reason to do what you're doing, merely call this snippet of code you have made all your changes. It will update all the elements in your rows to have the correct numbering.

```
var formElements = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByClassName('toUpdate');
for (var i=0; i<formElements.length; i++) {
    var e = formElements[i];
    e.id = 'new'+i;
}
```

There are quite a few variations on this if you didn't want to add a `class="toUpdate ..."` to each one. For example you were using regular form elements, you could iterate over the `<form>`'s elements. Or you could iterate through all the elements and pattern-match on the names or ids. Or if you are algorithmically generating this with javascript you could add each element to an array at the same time you add it to the DOM, for later use (like this update).